# Can't SAVE to Android SD Card Connected to PC

Tags: windows, android, sd-card, mobile-phone

I can connect my Galaxy A7 Android phone to my PC and the phone's internal memory shows up, but ONLY for **looking *up* files**. I can't SAVE files to the phone.

Here's what I'm seeing when trying to open or browse the phone's SD card from PC:

We can see the phone's SD Card:
[image]
Then, to save:

The phone's SD card disappears when trying to save:
[image]

If I try to OPEN a file physically DRAGGED over to the SD card from the PC, interestingly, it opens up appended with 1.

Further, if I CLICK on that dragged over file, it WILL open on the PC. But, after making any edits and clicking the "save" icon - which SHOULD save it in the same place...I see:

Odd append, and won't save to same place:

[image]

Put another way - I can SEE the phone's SD card when connected, but can't get it to show up as a place to save files to.

So far, I've followed all these fixes already, and no results:

https://www.alphr.com/android-showing-connected-pc/

https://www.howtogeek.com/195607/how-to-get-your-android-device-to-show-up-in-file-explorer-if-it-isnt/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAncPaIP55Q&ab_channel=GeekStreet

Please help! :)

Comment: File from Android phone are accessed via MTP protocol. This protocol does not allow direct reading or writing of files on the phone (like a network drive), so Windows downloads them to a temp file to open them. Any modification done by a Windows program is lost because Windows does not transfer the files back.

Comment: @Robert - First! THANK YOU!!! :)))!!! I understand the issue now. Is there any workaround that you know of? Here's my goal - to be able to store my PDF files on my Android Phone so that I can read them on-the-go while commuting and add highlights / comments to the files during long trips. Then, be able to WORK on those edited documents on the PC in my office.